# Non-System Disk Utilization is High

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 Pro, and for the couple of months I've had it, disk usage for non-system disks (aka, all disks except `C:/`) is almost always much higher than the drive Windows is installed on (`C:/`).

This can be shown in Task Manager:

[image]

..and in Resource Monitor:

[image]

Usage of my drives:

- C:/ (My Windows 8.1 Pro Installation)
- F:/ (My Projects Drive)
- H:/ (Some programs installed here, but NOT any of the programs I currently am running [inc. Adobe CS5.5 Premium Suite])
- L:/ (Local Storage of Google Drive Files)
- K:/ (Windows 7 System Images [from previous installation])

The drive which ***should*** be having the highest disk usage is `C:/` since  it has all the programs which are currently running.

Disk C:/ is a single SATA3 SSD attached to a SATA3 PCI card, whereas the other drives are attached directly to the motherboard; could this influence the disk utilization?

My question: why is my disk utilization higher than my system disk, and how can this usage be toned down?

Comment: I would fire up process explorer and poke around in there to see if you can see what kind of I/O is going on.  Should give some clues about what's going on with your `C:/` drive.

Comment: @jmreicha It's not the C:/ drive that has high usage, it's all my other drives.

Comment: Ah must have misread the question. Still, process explorer will give you some help figuring out what is going on with those drives.